# Discord.py How to make the bot check every new message?

Tags: discord.py

I'm using Discord.py how can I make the bot execute some operations when a user post a new message?

Comment: You're not very specific here, and also it's very important that you show what you tried. We can't just give you script. Show what you tried then you may get help. Other wise it's not good to use discord.py if you know nothing about it. Did you mean when a user says any message or a certain message? If any message then use `on_message` (can't also be used for a certain message but this is best to use `client.command()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend reading through the docs first before coming here to ask a question. However, you can use a client event and [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) to check every new message, for example:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "Hi":
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")
```